# Magnitude of each column in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an input matrix that has 3 rows and 1000 columns. Each column represents and x, y, z variable. I want to find the magnitude of each column and store that in an output matrix that has 1 row and 1000 columns.

This is my current attempt but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
output(1,:) = norm(input(3,:));
```

my input matrix looks like:

```
x1, x2,...,x1000
y1, y2,...,y1000
z1, z2,...,z1000
```

I want my output matrix to look like:

```
[magnitude(x1,y1,z1), magnitude(x2,y2,z2),...,magnitude(x1000,y1000,z1000)]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`norm(input(3,:))` will give you the norm of the 1000 elements of the third row.

Easy solution is to just run a for loop.

```
output = zeros(1,1000); %Preallocate space
for i = 1:length(output)  
  output(i) = norm(input(:, i));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's norm function only works for single vectors. Let A be the name of the matrix which columns you want to find the norm to. Then this command does the job:

```
norm_A = sqrt(sum(A.*A));
```

Here is an example:

```
>> A = [1:5; 1:5; 1:5]

A =

     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5

>> norm_A = sqrt(sum(A.*A))

norm_A =

    1.7321    3.4641    5.1962    6.9282    8.6603
```